# HTML 5 Three column layout

Tags: css, html, multiple-columns, navigationbar

I am still new to HTML 5. I am trying to build an index page but I have run into a few problems. I am trying to use a three column layout with some navigation links on the side and I want some navigation links under the header. I have tried several approaches with no luck. I am also trying to have a picture stretch between the two columns but I am not sure if I have my coding right since there is so much space between everything. I will post a picture of what I would like my index page to look. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```css
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}

main {
  margin: 0 210px 0 160px;
  padding: 1px 10px 20px 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  color: #000000
}

body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

aside {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: boreder-box;
  font-size: .70em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000 padding-top: 10px;
  clear: both;
}

#container {
  background-color: #969696;
  color: #000000;
  min-width: 960px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>St. Pete Flower Market</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header role="banner">
      <span><a href="#search">Search</a></span>
      <h1>St. Pete Flower Market</h1>

    </header>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="occasions.html">Occasions</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="flowers.html">Flowers</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="giftbaskets.html">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="deals.html">Deals</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <aside role="complementary">
    </aside>
    <main role="main" id="content">
      <h2><img src="roses.jpg" width="1148" height="300" alt="Roses"></h2>
      <h3>fjfjfwjif</h3>
      <footer role="contentinfo"> fjiefjwiofjewfjiewofjewo</footer>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in to flex or grid.

These can help you a lot if you are doing it by yourself.

Here's some great links to check out.

- GRID : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- Flex : https://www.google.com/url?q=https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjd9Ye_lo_ZAhVsplkKHfzoCp0QFggFMAA&client=internal-uds-cse&cx=008634746982114956312:jsnn6x4ou7o&usg=AOvVaw3oVZNdBcJm5oSz3KSIgI7Z

Either of these can help create that 3 column layout you want.

Also if you'd like you can use bootstrap 4 which can make your life easier.

- https://getbootstrap.com/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer a question. Answering using links to another site is not recommended as site links can change or be removed over time. You could improve this answer by giving an answer in your own words and then refer to the links as your source. That way this answer can still help someone in years to come.